# django get using _id cannot resolve keyword into field

Tags: django, foreign-keys

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Branch, null=True)

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

When I do:

```
x = Foo.objects.get(bar_id=2)
```

I get:

```
*** FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'bar_id' into field. Choices are: bar, id, name
```

Shouldn't bar_id use the foreign key id directly to look for the matching Foo?
I understand I can query the db first to get the Bar object and then use it in the get statement, but should I waste a query on this if the id is already in the Foo table?

(I'm using an old django and python for a legacy project: django 1.4 python 2.7.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `x = Foo.objects.get(bar__id=2)` with double underscore.

django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).

Answer (score 0):

```
x = Foo.objects.get(bar__id=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the SQL table is using `bar_id` as the name of the column for the ForeignKey, you need to [use `bar__id` to *traverse* the FK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).

Hopefully, Django will optimize this and don't do a real join to execute the query:

```
>>> print MyModel.objects.filter(bar__id=1).values('pk').query
SELECT "myapp_mymodel"."id" FROM "myapp_bar" WHERE "myapp_mymodel"."bar_id" = 1
# Let's compare this with a real joining... (assuming Bar has a `name` field)
>>> print MyModel.objects.filter(bar__name='Thing').values('pk').query
SELECT "myapp_mymodel"."id" FROM "myapp_bar" INNER JOIN "myapp_bar" ON (
      "myapp_mymodel"."bar_id" = "myapp_bar"."id"
) WHERE "myapp_bar"."name" = Thing
```